# Transferring a value from an object to Userform Text Box in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This code below works only after a second attempt and all others after that. What can I do to allow this code to pass the value client to the Userform called Portal in Textbox1 on first attempt?

I need the info to pass from the inputbox after a correct password has been entered to the Portal userform as I need to specify several different variables and I cannot write the code for the 70+ objects that will link to the userforms through this code in assign macro.

Any help will be appreciated if anyone else has had this issue.

I have tried clearing user form inputs on workbook open but this hasn't worked.

```
Sub object6_Click()
    Dim Password As Variant
    Password = Application.InputBox("Enter Password Here", "Password")

    Select Case Password
        Case Is = False
            Exit Sub
        Case Is = "plenish"
            Portal.Show
            client = "plenish"
            If Portal.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
                Portal.TextBox1.Value = client
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: tbh I tried your code and everything you need should work right from the get go :/

Comment: This is why it's so irritating! Hopefully there is another way to force this through to the user form as I have tried so many approaches now and at a loss as to why it's being temperamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code stops running after Portal.show

try this:

```
Sub object6_Click()
    Dim Password As Variant
    Password = Application.InputBox("Enter Password Here", "Password")

    Select Case Password
        Case Is = False
            Exit Sub
        Case Is = "plenish"
            client = "plenish"
            If Portal.TextBox1.Value = "" Then Portal.TextBox1.Value = client
            Portal.Show 'vbModeless
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be working now, thanks. I was working on the assumption that you would have to load the Userform first before being able to add values to its textbox's. This is interesting how it's passing on the values. Thanks for your input